# Redirect to different controller in groovy/grails

Tags: java, grails, groovy

I am working with groovy/grails technology, in that from one of the action called **changepassword** of LoginController, I want redirect at LogoutController's **index** action..

What should be done to achieve that ?

Thanks in advance...

Answer (score 10, accepted):

When in a `login` controller you can use the following in your action to redirect to another action on a different controller:

```
redirect(controller: 'logout', action:'index')
```

Answer (score 3):

May be the official documentation will be useful? [this](http://www.grails.org/Controllers+-+Redirects)

Comment: It's generally preferable to provide a minimum of information in your answer, so that the user knows *at least* what they will get if they click on the link.

Answer (score 2):

See [Controller Dynamic Methods](http://www.grails.org/Controller+Dynamic+Methods) - as simple as `redirect(action: 'index')`